# Image Button , image resoultion

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I am using android ImageButton, I want to resize the image so that it is equal to the default image that was on button which I  think was 48 pix by 48 pix

But still the image is not covering the whole button , I can see some gray area.

So my question is what should be the resolution of the image that i cover the image button completely. The size of the imagebutton will be default.

Comment: Personally, I've preferred just using and `ImageView` as buttons to avoid the grey border issue you're running into.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should set background of the ImageButton to null.
android:background="@null"